# How to push to something typed `string | string[]`

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, typing

I struggle with a field typed `string | string[]`.

I assign an array to it but if I want to push a string to it i get a type error.

For illustration see this fragment:

```
  let col: AgGridColumnProps = {
    ...
    type: [field.type.toLowerCase()]
  }

  for (const [ending, tmp] of Object.entries(nameEndingMap)) {
    if (theName.endsWith(ending)) {
      const typ: string = tmp[0]
      ...
      col.type.push(typ)
    }
  }
```

Results in this error:

```
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string | string[]'.
  Property 'push' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

The definition of `type` from [Ag-Grid](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/01e0497b34644a1e40a407600b3fe953c3040999/community-modules/core/typings/entities/colDef.d.ts#L100) is `type?: string | string[]`.

How can I make typescript understand, that `push`ing to `type` is valid here?

Edit: While

```
  let col: AgGridColumnProps = {
    cellClass: type2classMap[field.type.toLowerCase()],
    type: [field.type.toLowerCase()]

  }
```

does not compile due to thye error mentioned above,

```
  let col: AgGridColumnProps = {}
  col.cellClass = type2classMap[field.type.toLowerCase()]
  col.type = [field.type.toLowerCase()]
```

compiles fine. I'm still dumbfolded what is happening there. I also was unable to reproduce this issue on a minimal example as suggested by Mike S.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a union type, you will need to assert the type before using a type specific method/property;

So instead of:

```
strarr.push(item);
```

you write:

```
(strarr as string[]).push(item);
```

or (type safe):

```
if(Array.isArray(strarr)) strarr.push(item);
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsBOB5eBlBBBe8CGIoF5YEBLAOwHMoAfI+M8gbQF0BuAKA4DMBXUgY2DEA9qSgATISiEBbCMAAW9ABRwcWAFy1kaeJhwgAlJoBuQ4mKgBvNlFrYsAOjDcY8pQCIAEhAA2PoVAA6kLwPmLuBixQAPTRUAAK8EKQ8KBQ7s6u7uJCEDBQpELAUBAAHsRwUCJQoJDpqvTuNlAqCPbwUNj5DRTMBk4ubl6+-kEhYRHstsScSnq4DhXzIK1q8AYG1ra2qu0Drh7efgHBoeGRzQC+bJdAA)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! Unfortunately `(col.type as string[]).push(typ)` gets me "This expression is not callable.  Type 'String' has no call signatures."
`if(Array.isArray(col.type)) col.type.push(typ)` works but looks strange to me, because just a few lines up the compiler coulds see `type: [field.type.toLowerCase()]` and figure out, it's an array.
`const t = col.type as string[] ; t.push(typ)` also seems to work (?). Still feels I'm missing something here.

Comment: @max Can you provide a reproducible example? With `type?: string | string[]`, you shouldn't be getting any errors. I added a playground example in the answer.

Comment: Im not very good in setting up all dependenciy versions (typescript, AG-Grid, etc.) at all this playground sites. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-1salxp?file=index.tsx function setColFormat is the closest I could get AND IT DOES NOT EXIBIT THIS PROBLEM.